# Get the text inside a paragraph after an element

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the text inside a paragraph with jQuery.
But just the text after the href element.

```
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<a href="#" class="read_more">Lorem ipsum</a> 

Aliquam efficitur elit quis lacus interdum, a eleifend mauris maximus.</p>
```

The result is:

> Aliquam efficitur elit quis lacus interdum, a eleifend mauris maximus.

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Perhaps surround it with a `<span>`?

Answer (score 2):

wrap it inside a span and then get it.

```
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<a href="#" class="read_more">Lorem ipsum</a> 

<span class="desired_text">Aliquam efficitur elit quis lacus interdum, a eleifend mauris maximus.</span>

</p>
```

Then, using `text()`

```
$(".desired_text").text()
```

**UPDATE.**

If you cant modify your html, then just

```
 $(".text").text().split(" ")[1]
```

Comment: And how can I wrap a span after the href with jQuery ?

Comment: I can't change the html, I need to do that just with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution that I know of.

```
$("#main_div")
  .clone()    //clone the element
  .children() //select all the children
  .remove()   //remove all the children
  .end()  //again go back to selected element
  .text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just do that

```
$( "p.text" ).contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType !== 1;
  }).wrap( "<span></span>" );

$( ".read_more_a").next();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this if you don't want to wrap text in span as in @levi answer:-

```
var text = $(".text").html();
var txt = text.substring(text.indexOf("/a>")+3);
```